# Unknown provider's error throw when injecting constant

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am having some issues running my karma tests.

I have this service that works well, in which I inject a constant `CSRF_TOKEN` :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('App').factory("AuthenticationService", function($http,    $sanitize, SessionService, FlashService, CSRF_TOKEN) {

   var sanitizeCredentials = function(credentials) {
       return {
           email: $sanitize(credentials.email),
           password: $sanitize(credentials.password),
           csrf_token: CSRF_TOKEN
       };
   };
...
```

But when running `grunt test` command, Karma's error is :

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: CSRF_TOKENProvider <- CSRF_TOKEN <- AuthenticationService
```

**UPDATE**
My Karma.conf :

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'app/bower_components/xdomain/dist/0.6/xdomain.js',
      'app/bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
      'app/scripts/*.js',
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'test/mock/**/*.js',
      'test/spec/**/*.js'
    ],

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

And my constant defined in a bootstrap.js file to instantiate it before app starts :

```
'use strict';

angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    var app = angular.module('App');
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    $injector.invoke(function($http, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            $http.get("http://something/token").then(function(response) {
                app.constant("CSRF_TOKEN", response.data.csrf_token);
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['App']);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Do you know the solution so that Karma stop thinking my constant is a provider?

Comment: Can you share the constant and the karma conf?

Comment: It looks like the constant is only set up if there is an http call: `$http.get("http://something/token")`.  How do you make this happen in the karma test?

Comment: And BTW, this doesn't really look like a _constant_.  Maybe, your design needs a token service?

Comment: Im just calling once the url to give a unique token to my API so I don't think I need a service. And I tried to instante a simple constant in my app.js like `angular.module('accredFrontApp').constant('CSRF_TOKEN','myconst');` but the error remains the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seams like document's ready event is never thrown in your jasmine test and therefore constant is not defined in your `App` module. Try to mock `CSRF_TOKEN` constant in your module configuration section of the test:

**JavaScript**

```
describe('Test', function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('App', function($provide) {
      $provide.constant('CSRF_TOKEN', 'MOCK_CONSTANT'); // <= mock your constant
    });
  });

  // Tests go here

});
```

Comment: This doesn't change the error :/ I tried before to instantiate a constant normally with `angular.module('App').constant('CSRF_TOKEN','myconst');` but I had the same error running the tests...

Comment: @lightalex The problem is not in HOW you define a constant, but WHEN you do it. Are you sure that code inside `angular.element(document).ready()` is running at all? Did you try to modify test as in my example?

Comment: I can't see the solution. The mock is not the solution. Can someone point it to me ?